# How can kernel module communicate with user-space process during rmmod?

Tags: linux-kernel

I have a kernel module (a pseudo device driver actually) and also an auxiliary user-space process.

I want the kernel module to contact a user-space process during the process of rmmod, trigger the user-space process to do some clean-up work. I know I can send a signal from the kernel to the user process to trigger the clean-up, but I do need to send some other information to direct the user process as how to do the clean-up. (It is an array of integers, if that matters). I assume I can not pass any information along with the signal?

Do you guys know a way of doing it? I can not use ioctl, since the device would not be visible to the user-space process as it's being rmmod'ed..

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such a design does not fit well with how the kernel works.

Instead, you should make the module report itself as in-use until the cleanup has been completed (so causing `rmmod` to fail).  When you want to unload the module, you should trigger the userspace cleanup to happen, then perform the `rmmod` when it is complete (presumably with some kind of userspace script).

You could implement this by having the userspace daemon hold a file descriptor open to the device provided by the kernel module, closing it once the userspace cleanup has happened.

Comment: Why I want to do it during rmmod: my module is a block device driver. So as long as I don't perform rmmod, it might still take IO requests. I really really need those IO activity on that device to stop while I am doing clean-up. That's why I want to do it inside the rmmod runction...@caf

Comment: @yangsuli: So you just need the userspace process to first request the device to quiesce itself (failing any new IOs that are issued, and blocking until any outstanding IOs are complete); then perform the cleanup; then request the rmmod.

Comment: Well. I know in principle I should do that...But I just got lazy and hope kernel does that for me when doing rmmod. This is just for some test purpose. And forcing my device to quiesce is difficult to implement in my case because my driver maintains a LOT of states internally. I am looking for a shortcut here...@caf

Comment: @yangsuli: Ahh - no, the kernel doesn't force anything like that on an rmmod.  You have to implement that yourself either way - in most cases modules will simply refuse to unload if userspace processes still have them open (because their module use count is nonzero).  If your module allows itself to be removed while still in use, it will simply cause a kernel crash.

Comment: That's my point...If there is outstanding IO while I am doing rmmod, kernel will actually stops me from doing that...So when I am in the rmmod function, I can be comfortable that no one is messing up my internal device state. However, if I simply start the user process, I can not feel so safe. @caf